# Jenkins Multiconfiguration mark as unstable

Tags: groovy, jenkins, continuous-integration

I currently have a setup where I jobs running the same code on multiple different nodes, and am looking for a way to mark a build as "Unstable" instead of "Failed" if one configuration fails.  I've attempted to look into a Groovy postbuild script, but I haven't been successful as of yet.  Does anyone know of a way to mark a multiconfiguration build as Unstable if half or less of the configurations fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins **[Text-finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin)** allows to mark builds as unstable based on RegEx in console log and/or other files.

As for the requirement to have it done only if "half or less"... you will have to make that logic yourself.